# i wanna delete array element but i have a problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

i wanna delete array element but i have a problem.
i ever looking for google, and stackOverFlow's solution but.. i can't understand well.. and
how to treat well in my code.

for example,

```
let str = ('  a  b c d C b A ')
```

// i wanna array like that ( ["a", "b", "c", "d", "c", "b", "a"] )
// so, first i using replace method. (Unfortunately, blocked str.trim method from academy)
// after using replace method,

```
let blank = str.replace("  ","")
"a  b c d C b A "
```

// and i using split method,

```
let arr = blank.toLowerCase().split(" ")
```

// 'toLowerCase()' is need to solve next matter
and like that

```
["a", "", "b", "c", "d", "c", "b", "a", ""]
```

problem is begin,
i wanna delete "" element. but,
target an unspecified index, i cant using splice method.

maybe it need to 'for' ,

```
for(let i = 0 ; i < arr.length; i++) {
if(arr[i]==="") { ...i dont know what to doo.. }
}
```

Is my direction correct?
And what and how should we do it? i guess i cant using 'splice' method.. because of that..

Comment: console.log(str.replace(/\s+/g, "").split("").map(s => s.toLowerCase()));

Comment: Ohhh thank you it's helpful advice ! i will looking for about map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should try as code snippet**

```js
var array = ["a", "", "b", "c", "d", "c", "b", "a", ""];
var newArr = array.filter(function (el) {
  return el != "";
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let str = ('  a  b c d C b A ');
let arr = str.toLowerCase().split('').filter(e=>e!=' ');
```

May be it what you want